# Hide native validation tooltip

Tags: html

I have simple form with browser validation by pattern:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="+375 (__) ___-__-__" pattern="\+375\s\(\d{2}\)\s\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}" required />
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

1. Put there some text, like `123`
2. Submit form (tooltip will be shown)
3. Continue typing

In my case in Chrome validation continues work automatically and tooltip blinks every time I type a symbol. Can it be avoided somehow?

JSFiddle for check: https://jsfiddle.net/ypb36tpz/2/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the tooltip problem, but I think you have a wrong Regex for what you want. I think `^\+375\s\([0-9]{2}\)\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$` would work better